# increase speed compare_faces in face_recognition python

Tags: python, face-recognition

I want compare given photo(.jpg) with folder which contain 10000 photos(.jpg)

Here is my code:

```
import face_recognition

import os

path = 'D:\imageFaceRecog'

files = sorted(os.listdir(path))


known_image = face_recognition.load_image_file("C:\\Users\\Public\\Pictures\\Sample Pictures\\nikolay.jpg")
known_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(known_image)[0]
for f in files:
    print(f)
    unknown_image = face_recognition.load_image_file("D:\\imageFaceRecog\\"+f)
    
    unknown_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(unknown_image)[0]
    results = face_recognition.compare_faces([known_encoding], unknown_encoding)
    print(results)
```

But my code give me a speed approximately 35 comparisons in minute.

Are there any ways to increase the speed of comparisons ?

P.S I run this code in:
visual studio 2019,
Windows 7
4GB RAM
python 3.6
Intel HD Graphics

Answer (score 0):

While identification of face location is one the "haviest" stages in face recognition, you can trick face_recognition a litle and use Google Mediapipe for that:

```
import mediapipe as mp

MIN_FACEBOX_DIM = (30, 30) # minimal acceptable face box dimensions

mp_face_detection = mp.solutions.face_detection
boxes = []
encodings = []

face_detection = mp_face_detection.FaceDetection(min_detection_confidence=0.5)
iheigth, iwidth = image.shape[:2]
results = face_detection.process(image)
    if results.detections:
    # further with  results.detections:
        for d in results.detections:
            xmin = int(iwidth * d.location_data.relative_bounding_box.xmin)
            ymin = int(iheigth * d.location_data.relative_bounding_box.ymin)
            ymax = ymin + int(iheigth * d.location_data.relative_bounding_box.height)
            xmax = xmin + int(iwidth * d.location_data.relative_bounding_box.width)
            if (xmax - xmin) > MIN_FACEBOX_DIM[0] and (ymax - ymin)>MIN_FACEBOX_DIM[1]:
                boxes.append([ymin, xmax, ymax, xmin])

encodings.append(frfe(aligned_image, known_face_locations=[boxes],
                                           num_jitters=njits, model="large"))
```